# Is Gnome DPI aware?

Tags: gnome, dpi

Is Gnome fully DPI aware? I don't mean only fonts but also widgets like buttons, window borders etc.

Answer (score 4):

No. GTK+ does not use point sizes for everything yet. Many things still require pixel perfection, as common screens do not have high enough resolution to avoid being pixel perfect in certain areas.